# マウスホイールスクロールのスピード調整に関して

Tags: javascript, jquery

スクロールをするときのスピードを遅くするために下記を設定しました。
FF,IEの時はできたのですが、GCで見ると下記ではスクロールするとガタガタしてしまいます。
何か記述間違いありますでしょうか？

現在の状況です。
http://footmarkdays.web.fc2.com/test2/

```
<script>
var scrolly = 150;
var scrollySpeed = 150;
var easing = 'easeOutQuart';

$(function(){
    //$('html').mousewheel(function(event, mov){
    $('html').wheel(function(event, mov){

        var trg = $($.browser.safari ? 'body' : 'html');    
        scrolly = (mov > 0) ? trg.scrollTop() - scrollySpeed: trg.scrollTop() + scrollySpeed;

        $('html, body')
        .stop()
        .animate({scrollTop:scrolly}, 1000, easing);

        return false;
    });

        });
</script>
```

```
https://greasyfork.org/scripts/36987-jquery-mousewheel-3-1-13/code/jQuery%20Mousewheel%203113.js?version=240834
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/189460

Comment: 対処法がわからないですが、FFの場合はマウスwheelイベントが発火するとスクロールは動かないようですが、GCはマウスWheelイベントと同時にスクロールも動いているようです。

Answer (score 0):

このページにある内容が原因ではないでしょうか。

https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312

イベントリスナーがpassiveとして処理されているので、
イベント処理の中断が無視（return falseも含む）されているからだと思います。